# Where does Apache read $domain variable from?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

In my operational Wordpress enabled Ubuntu instance, I have a 000-default.conf file with the settings:

```
./apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:        ServerName $domain
./apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:        ServerAlias www.$domain
```

grepping for `\$domain` inside etc gives me basically only this file.

Where does Apache get this value when running my site?

---

full 000-default.conf:

```
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName $domain
        ServerAlias www.$domain

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Show full 000-default.conf

Comment: @Exampleperson Added. Do you see anything relevant?

Comment: @Adeerlike Please also show the part where the 000-default gets included in the main configuration.

Comment: @JohannesH. it's just `# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

Comment: The include includes `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` - you posted `sites-available/000-default.conf` above. Are you sure they're identical / symlinked?

Comment: I edited my reply below to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

`$domain` is *not* a pre-defined variable in Apache HTTPD. The [list of variables in the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars) does not have it.

As Environment variables are accessed using a `%{VAR}`-notation in Apache, so it is not read from the environment either.

It's also not in my 000-default.conf - which means it must be something specific to your setup.

And indeed it is! Wordpress includes that file in `sites-available` with `$domain` as a placeholder. During setup, the file gets copied into `sites-enabled` and the placeholder gets replaced. Look in `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and instead of `$domain`, there should be your domain.

Comment: Does it make sense [and how] for Apache to include it from a Wordpress PHP script?

Comment: What exactly do you want to include where? In general though, PHP cannot interact with the apache configuration. Apache reads that config during startup (unless you issue a reload), and parsing it happens way before any PHP interpreter is even invoked.

Comment: That's why I am wondering where it gets the value for $domain.  The only place my system has this variable is in PHP files for this site...

Comment: As I said - during wordpress installation, it should copy the actual domain into that apache config file. If you installed wordpress, and it still says $domain in apache, something is wrong - and this shouldn't work. Are you sure you're looking in your actual Apache-config and not in the wordpress teplates for it?